# connected but can't access network openVPN NAS

Tags: openvpn, network-attached-storage

We are a small engineering office of about 30 people. When I set-up my QNAP NAS TS219P+ as an openVPN server, I can connect *to* the network remotely but can't access anything inside the network. Bit of background:

- initially used PPTP and that worked fine
- have tried from multiple systems (Win. 10 - our main target OS - with
  openVPN GUI; mac OS X with tunnelblick) which leads me to believe
  it's on the server end rather than the client end
- simply can't access/ping any local resources (e.g. NAS login page)

Few details:

- router forwards UDP port 1194 to the NAS (as per openVPN setup),
  which leads me to believe it's a setup/config issue on the NAS end
- all users have 'openVPN'
  ticked in 'connection privileges' everything's on the same subnet
  mask (LAN infrastructure and openVPN IP address pool)

Few interesting things once I'm connected (via VPN) to the network:

- the computer is visible from the 'connection list', but with an IP outside of the IP address pool as specified in the openVPN IP address pool)
- I can ping the IP address of the computer that's VPN'ed in, but response times are extremely slow (~600ms)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without the log information. I had a similar problem on a QNAP TS-493 ProII and the solution was to change the tun device from QNAP's default `tunXXXX` to simply `tun` in the .ovpn file.